# document.documentElement.offsetHeight throwing undefined error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mobile, cross-browser

#### Short Version

Trying to access the document.documentElement.offsetHeight on IEMobile 7.11 throws an unspecified error. Why?

#### Long Version

I'm working on fixing some Javascript meant to be run on handheld devices (not phones, the kind delivery guys use). The devices have a few different OSes and browser versions, though, so compatibility is a concern.

The problem code is in a method called during the body element's onLoad and onResize events. I was able to fix the problem on one device using the document.documentElement.offsetHeight property, but when I try to use it on the other device, it gives an error.

Now, I was expecting to have to do all sorts of quirky compatibility checks, but this particular error is interesting because I have no idea why it's happening. All of the following cause an error:

```
var str = document.documentElement.offsetHeight
var str = String(document.documentElement.offsetHeight)
alert(document.documentElement.offsetHeight)
```

So it appears that simply trying to access the property at all throws the error. I checked that the documentElement object exists, and it does, so it's not a case of calling properties on a null. I thought it might be because offsetHeight isn't defined, even though that should just return null, so I checked the documentElement's properties with the following loop to be sure:

```
var str = "";
for (var prop in document.documentElement) {
    str += prop + "\n";
}
```

But the offsetHeight property is definitely there on the object, although I have no idea what value it is.

I tried catching the error, and it didn't give me anything helpful; both the error.description and error.message were empty, so I looked up the error number (-2147467259) and found it means "Unspecified Error", short for "you're on your own".

As far as my own knowledge goes, this error is completely inexplicable. So I come to Stack Overflow seeking wisdom.

#### Miscellaneous Info

- OS: Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional
- Browser: IEMobile 7.11

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetheight.asp

Comment: In this: `document.documentElement.style` you're looping though `style`. not `documentElement`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I copy-pasted that from modified code that I was using to loop through a few different thigns. I'll update it.

Comment: @apandit : I'm not sure what you're trying to say there. I checked the w3schools page before coming here, and it didn't have anything relevant to my situation.

Comment: @Reikim Sorry...thought you were trying to do something else.  Are the lines of code that are giving you the error being called after the document has loaded?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure. It's tied to the body by `onload="problematicFunction();"`, which in theory should only fire after everything's been loaded, but I've seen IE do weirder things before. I thought of that, though, so I bound the function to a button on the page and mashed it, and still got the same error; so it's not because it's trying to access things before load.

Comment: @Reikim What does adding `str += document.documentElement[prop] + "\n"` inside the `for` loop give you?  Does it error out as well?

Comment: @apandit Yes, it does. It really does seem like it just doesn't want me to read that one property. Maybe it's a security thing...though that wouldn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Is it maybe the content-type coming from the server? Is it "application/javascript" and not "text/javascript".  See accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231827/iemobile-7-11-with-external-javascript

Comment: No, that's definitely not the problem, because the javascript is in fact running. (I tried it just for kicks, though.)

I think I'm just going to write this off as "IEMobile 7 hates you", because I've been playing around with about fifty different workarounds for the original problem and none of them work right for various reasons.